# SKStoreReviewController not working

Tags: ios, xcode, rate, skstorereviewcontroller

Why is "SKStoreReviewController's" send button is greyed out and doesn't respond on touch? 
Maybe it's related to that I am in DEBUG mode?

Comment: How did it go? Did you find out if it is DEV mode caused that?

Comment: Yes, It is.
I submitted the app to the app store and the send button worked.

Comment: Cool thanks Karen. I've submitted mine as well. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is only enabled **after** the app is downloaded **from the app store**.

During development, or even release build, it is grayed out.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same doubt, then asked Apple Technical Support. They confirmed the button would be enabled in production (when app is live).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same question and have tried RELEASE mode(dev provision&sign). The submit button is also disabled.

Maybe we are in DEV mode and the rating is real, So they block us submitting rating in dev mode.

Comment: Having the same problem. and yes, also suspecting that what you say might be the reason why its greyed out. Makes sense but Apple's doc should state this. I haven't found it yet.